# pointers to pointers to strings and strcmp

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Assume we have an Address class

```
class Address{
public:
  char addr[6];
}
```

If we have Address1 and Address2 objects. What does this line compare?

```
strcmp((char *)&(Address1.addr), (char *)&(Address2.addr))
```

addr is a pointer to a character array. &addr is a pointer to a pointer to a character array and then you cast this into a character array. So is this supposed to actually compare the two character arrays?

Comment: `addr` is not a pointer, it's an array. Anyway, `strcmp(address1.addr, Address2.addr);` would make so much more sense...

Comment: this is undefined behavior. strcmp is being asked to treat 2 pointers as strings. Take out the casts and read the compilers error message

Comment: [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) expects pointers to char, not double pointers to char.

Comment: @pm: It's well-defined but obfuscated.

Comment: "addr is a pointer to a character array" - no, it isn't; its an array, specifically `char[6]`, and *converts* to a `char *` when used in the proper expression context. "&addr is a pointer to a pointer to a character array" - no, it isn't. It is a pointer to a `char[6]`. I.e `char (*)[6]`. It is **never** a `char**`. There is enough inaccurate info in nearly every assumption you made in this code that perhaps solid understanding everything *apart* from that hideous line *first* would be well-warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's be clear: There is no pointer to pointer in sight anywhere.
What we have is a pointer to an array of 6 `char`.

Because the address of an array is always the address of its first element, the cast makes `(char *)&(Address1.addr)` equivalent to `&Address1.addr[0]`.

That is still far too complicated though, in most contexts (exceptions are `sizeof`, address-of (`&`) and some others), an array decays to a pointer to its first element on use.

Thus, it can and should be written `Address1.addr` instead.

Now if those arrays contain 0-terminated strings, all is well, though there's no excuse for the obfuscation.
It should be:

```
strcmp(Address1.addr, Address2.addr)
```

Comment: It is not fine though, because you are casting a `char **`  as `char *`.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Why wouldn't it be fine? They are guaranteed to point to the same address.

Comment: You're absolutely right actually :) Hmm, interesting. But frankly I'm not sure the OP should be encouraged to think this is fine.

Comment: @Deduplicator It is not my code, so I am just trying to understand why they did it that way. Are you saying the pointer to the pointer is pointing to the same address of the character array?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Oh, he should know it's fine as in well-defined and valid. But he should also know it's absolutely inexcusable obfuscation.

Comment: @Keeto: It's not a pointer to a pointer, but a pointer to an array of lenght 6 with elements of type `char`.

Comment: @Deduplicator hmm Address1.addr is a pointer to an array. right? so what is &(Address1.addr)?

Comment: @Keeto The characters of `addr` are stored contiguously. Now because `addr` is the only member of any such instance, say `Addess a`, we also know that `&a.addr` (the address of the first char) is also the same as `&a`.

Answer (score 2):

When passing an array `T arr[N];` to a function, it will be promoted (or demoted, or whatever you want to call it) to `T *`, so just doing

```
 strcmp(ddress1.addr, Address2.addr);
```

should do the trick.

Or use `std::string` and don't worry about `strcmp` at all (and you don't have to worry about `addr` having more than 5 characters, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
// "std::string" might be better, but OK...
class Address{
public:
  char addr[6];
}
...

// Compare one address with another
int iret = strcmp (address1.addr, address2.addr);

// Or, equivalently, 
int iret = strcmp (&address1.addr[0], &address2.addr[0]);
```

Here's a good discussion of C-style strings (null-terminated character arrays):

https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/string/intro/

And here's a good discussion of what it means that "arrays decay into pointers":

http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr